# Is it posible to change users hometown thru Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I Couldnt find any info about changing users setting in facebook api...

It's a app on facebook and I want the user to be able to change the hometown.

Sounds simpel!

Comment: Nope, I don't think that's possible, checked their docs and don't see any info on that.